# MS SQL Layer - Invalid Layer Error when Attempting to Load a Table

Tags: qgis, sql-server, connection

I have a table called [stg].[Stops] in SQL Server that I would like to load in QGIS for data analysis. This is the first time I use the MSSQL Server connection option in QGIS. Unfortunately, even though QGIS recognizes the table and its **geography** data type. When I attempt to connect, I get an **invalid layer error**.

Here is a screenshot of the menu:

[image]

and here is the error:

> 2017-01-25T11:07:37   1   dbname='TK463' host=******* srid=4326
>   type=Point table="stg"."Stops" (GEOM) sql= is an invalid layer - not
>   loaded

What could possible cause that?

Comment: Do you have a primary key field or a unique OBJECTID or ROWNUM field in your data?

Comment: Thanks I thought I had a PRIMARY KEY, but for some reason I did not! This fixes the issue thanks again!

Comment: Great! Keep in touch with any mssql / qgis issues - we use it every day!

Comment: This also worked for me. I wonder why this is not mentioned as an answer!

Comment: The issue for me was that the sql server table name contained a full stop

Answer (score 2):

Posting DPSSpatial's comment as an answer:

> Check you have a primary key field or a unique OBJECTID or ROWNUM field.

You can add this to a view by:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY label ASC) AS ID#
```

where label is any column you choose.

Answer (score 1):

Following reply worked for QGIS 3.4

The case:
On the same server, created an exact copy of a polygon table on a different db

```
SELECT * INTO db2.dbo.geom_table_copy FROM db1.dbo.geom_table
```

While QGIS was reading the original table normally, when attempting to insert the copied table I would get

```
WARNING    dbname='db2' host=www.myhost.com user='user' password='pwd' srid=4326 type=Polygon disableInvalidGeometryHandling='0' table="dbo"."geom_table_copy" (POLYGON) sql= is an invalid layer - not loaded
```

The key seems to be in the last argument `sql=`. For some reason, on the specific db, the sql field (filter) was not recognised as blank (even though it seemed so) but as something invalid.
I fixed the error by editing filters, setting something simple as filter i.e. `ID <=100` and then erasing it. This reset the sql field to empty and the layer was properly loaded.

Comment: How did you add this filter?

Comment: Three ways to do so:
1. double click on the layer and wait for the filter window to pop up ("Query Builder"
2.Select the table and click "set filter" on the lower right of the data source manager window
3.Click the SQL column, at the row that is the table you are interested in and directly type an SQL argument